# drupal 7 error when uploading with new field

Tags: drupal

I've got a very strange problem using drupal 7. I've got a wbesite running and using views and content types I have been able to build a lot of functionality. Now the following occurs:

When I add a new field to a content type (new or existing) of the the type file or image, I have this field in the form but when I try to upload a file or image using this form it gives an error "The file could not be uploaded" or the full error (from the recent log messages): "The upload directory public:// for the file field field_katapult_voorpagina could not be created or is not accessible. A newly uploaded file could not be saved in this directory as a consequence, and the upload was canceled."

Strangely, when I upload a file or image using an older existing field (pointing to the same directory: public://) it does not give an error and the files upload without a problem. So this makes me think that the server settings are actually set properly.

Anybody who can help me with this problem?
If not, can anybody point me in the right direction as to where I can find the files that handle the upload process in drupal 7?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check a couple of things :

- where is your public files folder, and if that is writable by the webserver ( in /admin/config/media/file-system )
- where does your working field send files (it might be a different directory), and if it is, use that for the new fields as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The strange thing is that it seems as if the folders are set exactly the same and that the public files folder is set correctly as well. Is there maybe a field in the database where I can check this exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Check you file destination directory setting of new image field. Do not include preceding or trailing slashes. This field supports tokens. 
You can also check max, min resolutions, file upload limit, image style (if it is new image style other than thumbnail/ or existing) & number of values ( if it set to 1 you can't upload 2 or more). Finally you have to set it public files type.

Comment: I've set everything correctly. It works on older content types but fails on newer ones. I think there is something wrong with the streamwrapper. A directory that is writable if I use the direct location (/sites/default/files) but when I use the streamwrapper public:// it is not writable...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the files folder permission.